# how to require("shopify_app") when migrate Ruby on rails app with Webcker to Vite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, vite, shopify-app

In the fully working Ruby on Rails app with webpacker, I have
`require("shopify_app")` in app/javascript/application.js
However, migration to Vite failed  with `require is not defined` in browser console

When I try `import "shopify_app";` error
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "shopify_app"

errors also with the `import "@shopify/app";`
[commonjs--resolver] Failed to resolve entry for package "@shopify/app".

Answer (score 0):

The `require("shopify_app")` doesn't search within the /node_modules/ directory but scans your app structure for the JavaScript file. To resolve this, use `import "../shopify_app/index"` or `import "../shopify_app/shopify_app"` to reference the /shopify_app/shopify_app.js file located one level above application.js file.